# Call a C# .net .dll script using PHP

Tags: c#, php

I have a C# .net dll script that calls a SQL stored procedure that `SELECT`s data in order to do run relevant methods.

I need to run the dll using PHP as my entire application is built in PHP.

What is the best way of doing this?

I'm not experienced at all with C#.

**EDIT**

I successfully registered the .net dll using:

```
RegAsm.exe DllName.dll /tlb:DllName.tlb
```

I should now be able to use PHP's `COM()` method as described below to call the dll's functions/methods.

But will these functions still be accessible through the `COM()` method as the .net dll was registered as an assembly? Does it make a difference?

**EDIT**

After registering the .net dll assembly I get an error message when I try to call the method using `COM()`:

```
"PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Failed
 to create COM object `DllName.ClassName': Invalid syntax"
```

**EDIT**

Tried using:

```
new DOTNET('DllName, Version=4.0.30319.33440, Culture=neutral,
PublicTokenKey=14843e0419858c21', 'ClassName');
```

got an `internal server 500` error

Is this because PHP doesn't communicate with .net 4 assemblies?

Comment: best way is to convert the query to a PHP implementation. You could also use the `exec()` php function, but I think use of this code when the frontend isn't the shell is considered bad practice..

Comment: I don't understand the C# language enough to convert to PHP. That was my first thought lol. But the script is greek to me and it seems like it's calling c# functions.

Comment: What do you mean by a C# script?  C# is compiled into an exe or dll.

Comment: Somewhere, somehow the query should be deducted, but without sourcecode, we cannot give an accurate answer to this...

Comment: the script is a .dll file

Comment: Could I load the dll code using `COM`? How would this work without parsing any variables?

Comment: So, the C# assembly has a method that you like to call with some parameters and at the end this method calls a SQL stored procedure, where these parameters are involved somehow? So if you don't understand the C# code, you maybe should trace the SQL server to see the sql statement and how the parameters are interweaved there. Then built the same in PHP.

Comment: Maybe you should post your C# code here and we can give you a little insight, what happens there.

Answer (score 8):

### Option 1: Use the DLL

You can call the function using PHP's COM class.

You'll need to be running PHP on Windows, which I assume you are if you're using a C# DLL.

**Steps:**

1. Register the DLL using the command `regasm yourdllname.dll` in Command Prompt or the Run dialog.
   You have one *RegAsm.exe* for each version of .NET installed on your computer, so make sure to execute the one for the version of .NET that the DLL targets by running it from *%windir%\Microsoft.NET\AppropriateVersion*.
2. Create a COM object in PHP that references the class name of the DLL.
3. Call the function, which will be available as a method of the COM object you've created.

**Example:**

```
$object = new COM('MyDllProjectName.MyDllClassName');
$object->myMethod();
```

### Option 2: Rewrite in PHP

As has been mentioned, the cleaner, cross-platform option is to re-implement the SQL query in PHP directly, especially if your only reason for using the DLL is to run a query.

Comment: Option 3 Access the DLL through a webservice

Comment: I'm confused, where does the `myMethod()` come from? is it instantiated there? how then do I call it?

Comment: You'd replace `myMethod` with the name of the method (function) that calls the SQL stored procedure in your DLL.

Comment: I tried registering the dll but I got an error saying that `..the-entry point DllRegisterServer was not found`

Comment: Try using `regasm` (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\YourVersion\RegAsm.exe) instead of `regsvr32`. The syntax is the same: `regasm yourdllname.dll`.

Comment: I managed to register the assembly using `regasm.exe DllName.dll /tlb:DllName.tlb` but will this assembly still be able to be called using the `COM()` method?

Answer (score 2):

Using COM directly has many caveats and issues.

There is a library called NetPhp that abstracts on top of COM using reflection, so that you can call ANY .dll from within PHP without hassle:

http://www.drupalonwindows.com/en/blog/calling-net-framework-and-net-assemblies-php